# How to get value of a key by referencing another key in the same JSON?? Also how to add string to the end of uri?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

Please refer to the JSON below : -

```json
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "creationTime": "2022-06-02T10:28:28.765+03:00",
            "deviceId": "43432103",
            "deviceName": "P25-SC-0228",
            "id": "121985460",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "com_cumulocity_model": {
                "op": "s",
                "param": "waterStartDateTime",
                "value": "1/2/2018, 7:30:00 AM"
            },
            "description": "Generate Plan"
        },
        {
            "creationTime": "2022-06-02T10:28:36.276+03:00",
            "deviceId": "43432103",
            "deviceName": "P25-SC-0228",
            "id": "121985465",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "com_cumulocity_model": {
                "Mode": 0,
                "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
            },
            "description": "Stop Station"
        }
    ],
    "statistics": {
        "currentPage": 1,
        "pageSize": 5
    }
}
```

Please find my code below : -

```
namespace handleDeviceOperations
{
    
class Program
{

string operationID = String.Empty;
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
    var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var httpClientFactory = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

    var httpClientGetOperations = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("getOperations");
    var request1 = await httpClientGetOperations.GetAsync("");

    if (request1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseMessage1 = await request1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(responseMessage1);
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseMessage1);

        RootObject myDeserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseMessage1);
        
        if (obj["operations"].HasValues)
        {
            foreach(var item in myDeserializedObject.operations)
            {
                switch(item.description)
                {
                    case "Generate Plan":
                        var gen_plan=JObject.Parse(responseMessage1)["operations"];
                        string[] gen_plan_list_operationID =gen_plan.Select(o => (string) o["id"]).ToArray();
                        JObject[] gen_plan_list_payload = gen_plan.Select(o => (JObject) o["com_cumulocity_model"]).ToArray();
                        break;

                    case "Stop Station":
                        var stop_st=JObject.Parse(responseMessage1)["operations"];
                        string[] stop_st_list_operationID =stop_st.Select(o => (string) o["id"]).ToArray();
                        JObject[] stop_st_list_payload = stop_st.Select(o => (JObject) o["com_cumulocity_model"]).ToArray();

                        var httpClientStopStation = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("executeOperations");
                        var request4 = await httpClientStopStation.PostAsync("");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddHttpClient("getOperations", options =>
    {
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.com?deviceId=43432103");

        options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic","auth value");
    });

    services.AddHttpClient("executeOperations", options =>
    {
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl.com/"+operationID);
        options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic","auth value");
        options.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.com.nsn.xyz.operation+json");
    });
    
}
public class RootObject
{
    public List<operation> operations { get; set; }
}
public class operation
{
    public golfController com_cumulocity_model { get; set; }
    public string description {get; set;}
}
public class golfController
{
    public int mode { get; set; }
    public string StopStationPayload { get; set; }
}
}
}
```

#### Question #1

In the switch case I want to fetch the value of `com_cumulocity_model` and `id` which belongs to the same JSON Object where case(value_of_description) is satisfied.
For example :
If `case "Stop Station":` is satisfied, I want to fetch the equivalent value of `com_cumulocity_model` and `id` inside it i.e. `{"Mode": 0,"StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"}` and `"121985465"` respectively. It must be compared to the value inside case and fetched on based of that.

#### Question #2

How do we add this value of `id = "121985465"` which we discussed above to the end of th url for making PostAsync request inside `case("Stop Station")` in lines `var httpClientStopStation = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("executeOperations"); var request4 = await httpClientStopStation.PostAsync("");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short way. If you need just com_cumulocity_model

```
var operations = JObject.Parse(json)["operations"];

var com_cumulocity_model = operations.Where(o => (string) o["description"] == "Stop Station")
.Select(o => o["com_cumulocity_model"])
.FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(com_cumulocity_model.ToString());
```

result

```
{
  "Mode": 0,
  "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
}
```

But if you need the whole data you can use this code for deserializing json.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

classes

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Operation> operations { get; set; }
    public Statistics statistics { get; set; }
}
public class Operation
{
    public DateTime creationTime { get; set; }
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public string deviceName { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public ComCumulocityModel com_cumulocity_model { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
public class ComCumulocityModel
{
    public string op { get; set; }
    public string param { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public int? Mode { get; set; }
    public string StopStationPayload { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    public int currentPage { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
}
```

you can  just remove Statistics class and statitics property from Data if you dont need it. The same about another properties

Now you can use Linq to get any data, for example

```
ComCumulocityModel com_cumulocity_model = data.operations
.Where(o => o.description == "Stop Station")
.Select(o => o.com_cumulocity_model)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

result (in json format)

```
{
  "Mode": 0,
  "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
}
```

how to print

```
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting=Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    };
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(  com_cumulocity_model,  jsonSettings));
```

Comment: And how will I get the value of the relevant ```id``` and ```com_cumulocity_model``` based on the case(value_of_description)?

Comment: @saurabhdhyani see my update

Comment: Wow!!! That's some magic you did there. I'm doing changes as per my need from the example given by you. Any idea about #Question 2??

Comment: @saurabhdhyani I am sorry but I don't understand what are trying.

Comment: No worries, how do I get this ```{
                "Mode": 0,
                "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
            }``` from ```com_cumulocity_model``` using same concept?

Comment: Hey, there's slight difference in the example you've given in the last part. Notice the value inside ```"StopStationPayload"``` in my desired result above.

Comment: @saurabhdhyani I am sorry, but  your json is not strongly valid.  Since Stopstationpayload is a string in your json, when  my code deserializet it converted a string to an object as it is supposed to be.

Comment: @saurabhdhyani if you want a string , just serialize it back to json.

Comment: Although I agree with you on the JSON structure, but I really have no option but to use it as it is.

Comment: @saurabhdhyani It is uselles as it is, you can not get any info

Comment: The value inside ```"StopStationPayload"``` needs to be passed as a string in a Post request for what I know. I don't really know how the destination is handling it. It's up to them.

Comment: @saurabhdhyani Ok, i returned it back

Comment: Even I tried the same thing which you've just updated, but somehow I'm not able to print the outcome.

Comment: @saurabhdhyani I added how to print

Comment: It prints ```[{"ControllerAddress":11,"StationAddress":26}]``` for me. I wanted to know how you achieved to print this : ```{
  "Mode": 0,
  "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
}```

Comment: Wow!! That Shortcut you gave really is a game changer for me. Couldn't thank you enough.